# xpages fileupload creates 2 files

Tags: file-upload, xpages

I transported an xpage from 9.00 server and extlib to an 9.01
rebuild it etc, and now got a few oddies:

amongst others, my fileupload control creates 2 instead of 1 file attachment from a selected file (e.g. filename.txt plus filename-2.txt)

The control's code:

```
    <xp:fileUpload
    id="fileUpload4" value="#{fback.SolutionAtt}">
    <xp:eventHandler
    event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
    refreshId="tdUpload4" disableValidators="true">
    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.HasUpload = "2"}]]>        
    </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:fileUpload>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe File upload using partial refreshed was introduced in 9.0.1.
maybe you have some code on your page that did not work before that started working with 9.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Same issue on a XPage with multiple fileupload controls (each bounded to different field). For one file everything was OK, two entered files were saved as 4 files (both were duplicated), three files were saved as 9 (3 files for each) and so on.

Solution: Embed each fileupload along with it's related filedownload control in a panel and set partial update in **onchange event** of the fileupload control.

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm that the solution above works for the following IBM APAR: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO82247

Answer (score 0):

Thomas, yes, that might be the reason.

I did a refresh of a certain table cell with an "upload" button (which did nothing else than another partial refresh and showed the file in an download control).

I now reinserted the upload control to my page and can trigger a direct refresh in the onchange event of the upload control. So as soon as the user chooses a file via the upload control, it is shown in the download control, and - that's the difference! - the upload is empty again.

Thx, Uwe